# Using Bazel to generate coverage report

Tags: code-coverage, bazel

I am using genhtml command to generate html coverage report from Bazel generated coverage.dat file:

```
genhtml bazel-testlogs/path/to/TestTarget/coverage.dat --output-directory coverage
```

The problem with using genhtml is that I have to provide the paths to the coverage.dat files (which are generated in bazel-testlogs/..) Is it possible to fetch those coverage.dat files as an output from another rule?

I would like to not have to call genthml command directly, but have Bazel handle everything.

Comment: Hi, Have you ever met `ERROR: output '_coverage/_coverage_report.dat' was not created` when run `bazel coverage`

Comment: @stamaimer Do not recall this particular error, this was a while ago...

Comment: Hi, Can you remember the version of gcc you use to compile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to get coverage.dat files as an output of a bazel rule. However, I was able to wrap all the locations of all the .dat files as srcs to a filegroup in WORKSPACE directory:

```
filegroup(
    name = "coverage_files",
    srcs = glob(["bazel-out/**/coverage.dat"]),
)
```

and then use that filegroup in a custom .bzl rule that wraps the genthml command to generate html coverage report. So now I only have to call

```
bazel coverage //path/... --instrumentation_filter=/path[/:]
```

command to generate the coverage.dat files, generate html report and zip it up. Thus, bazel handles everything.

Comment: Can you show how you used the `filegroup`  and `genhtml` in combination to generate the final `index.html` coverage report? Did you use `genrule`? I added both `filegroup` and `genrule` in `BUILD` file in the root directory of my workspace but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @PavanManjunath not able to find all the code. I do have a custom .bzl file that uses run_shell with cmd to run python ```coverage html``` command, which generates the html file. Not sure if this is helpful, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @Zeitgeist i don't understand, you can't post the code? or you can't find it? can you please share how you generate the HTML?

Comment: @sgammon Correct, I do not have access to the code, have been on a different project for years. To generate HTML file, I downloaded `genhtml` executable using `http_file()` in WORKSPACE, and then I created a custom bzl rule in which I incorporated a cmd command that runs that executable. (Being this was done so long ago, there are probably better ways to do things now)

Answer (score 4):

Bazel added support for [C++ coverage](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-website/blob/79e49346cbfae1803da53525fa56099a086af9b4/roadmaps/coverage.md)  (though I couldn't find much documentation for it).

I was able to generate a combined coverage.dat file with

```
bazel coverage -s \
  --instrument_test_targets \
  --experimental_cc_coverage \
  --combined_report=lcov \
  --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main \
  //...
```

The coverage file gets added to `bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat`

Comment: Which bazel version are you using?

Comment: I tested with version 0.21.0

Comment: FWIW, your link is dead

Comment: use bazel version 6.x to get the report .dat in $(bazel info output_path)/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat

Answer (score 0):

**For Java based project we can get code coverage in following way**

**To get coverage for complete module ->**

1. Running coverage for complete project module. Run following command ->

```
bazel coverage ... --compilation_mode=dbg --subcommands --announce_rc --verbose_failures --jobs=auto  --sandbox_debug --build_runfile_links --combined_report=lcov --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main
```

2. Then run following command from parent project directory to get html view. Html report is generated in `output-directory-name` we specified. From that open `index.html` to see coverage report.

```
genhtml -o <output-directory-name> bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
```

`bazel-out` directory usually gets created in project parent directory(e.g. where bazel `WORKSPACE` file is present)

**To get coverage for specific IT/Test in a module ->**

1. Running coverage for for specific IT/Test in a module. Run following command from project/sub-project directory ->

```
bazel coverage <class-name-of-Test-or-IT> --compilation_mode=dbg --subcommands --announce_rc --verbose_failures --jobs=auto  --sandbox_debug --build_runfile_links --combined_report=lcov --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main
```

2. Then run following command from parent project directory to get html view. Html report is generated in `output-directory-name` we specified. From that open `index.html` to see coverage report.

```
genhtml -o <output-directory-name> bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
```