# How to properly handle test coverage report (HTML) generation with Bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, starlark

### Goal

I would like to handle the entire process of generating the HTML report with test coverage data through Bazel.

### Components

In order to achieve my goal I understand that the following components are necessary:

- **[lcov .dat file](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov):** *provides information about
  what parts of a program are actually executed (i.e. "covered") while running a particular test case* . I can generate the required lcov files for my project by running `./bazelw query "attr(name, '.*test_main', //...)" | xargs ./bazelw coverage --combined_report=lcov` (all my test targets are named `test_main`, that's how I can execute the `coverage` command in all of them and combine the results with `--combined_report=lcov`;
- **[genhtml](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov/blob/master/bin/genhtml)**: an executable that can parse the lcov file and generate a HTML test report out of it (the final goal);
- **coverage.blz:** A custom bazel rule that takes the `.dat` file and the `genrule` binary
  as inputs and spits the final HTML and its deps (images and other HTMLs);

### What I was able to do so far...

**Create an executable script for genhtml**

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, however, it seemed reasonable to me at this point:

```
#!/bin/zsh

TOOLS_ROOT="${HOME}/.devxp/tools"
LCOV_BIN_HOME="${TOOLS_ROOT}/lcov/bin"
LCOV_GIT_REPO="https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov.git"
GENHTML="${LCOV_BIN_HOME}/genhtml"


function main () {
  if [[ ! -f "${GENHTML}" ]]; then
    _install &> /dev/null
  fi

  "${GENHTML}" "${@}"
}

function _install () {
  mkdir -p "${LCOV_HOME}"
  pushd "${TOOLS_ROOT}" || true
  git clone "${LCOV_GIT_REPO}"
  cd "${LCOV_HOME}" || true
  make install
  popd &> /dev/null || true
}

main "${@}"
```

**Create a file group to access the .dat in the repository**

Following the suggestions from - [Using Bazel to generate coverage report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447218/using-bazel-to-generate-coverage-report);

```
filegroup(
    name = "coverage_files",
    srcs = glob(["bazel-out/**/coverage.dat"]),
    visibility = [
        "//visibility:public"
    ]
)
```

This lives in my repository's root `BUILD` file

**Start my custom rule**

On file `coverage_report.bzl`

```
def _coverage_report_impl(ctx):
    dat_lcov_file = ctx.attr.coverage_files

coverage_report = rule(
    implementation = _coverage_report_impl,
    attrs = {
        "coverage_files": attr.label(),
    },
)
```

In the context of the custom rule implementation, I have the following questions:

- **QUESTION 1:** I don't know if at this point the .dat file was already generated since it requires `bazel coverage` to have ran. Can I force bazel coverage from here?
- **QUESTION 2:** I don't know how to get reference to my executable `genhtml` tool inside here. My plan was to do something like `genhtml *.dat -o output`;
- **QUESTION 3**: I don't know how to specify the output files of the `genhtml` as the output for this rule (as you can see this is the first time I attempt to implement my own rule);

Any help is very much appreciated!

**Reference Material**

- [Using Bazel to generate coverage report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447218/using-bazel-to-generate-coverage-report);
- [BazelCon 2018 Day 2: Collecting Code Coverage With Bazel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P51Rgcbxhyk)
- [Bazel Rules Tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules-tutorial.html)