# bazel coverage results are incomplete

Tags: bazel

The problem I'm running into is that my `bazel coverage` output coverage data feels incomplete.

For example, I have a project with 10 source files, and 1 test file (which tests only 1 source file).

- Run `bazel clean && bazel coverage --combined_report=lcov -- //src/...:all`
- Verify coverage data generated with `find -L -type f -name 'coverage.dat'`

Notice that:

- There exists 1 coverage file for each test run
- (Problem!) There is no coverage data for the untested source files

Does anyone know how to configure bazel to generate a complete coverage report, which includes the untested source files as well?

Comment: Tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P51Rgcbxhyk ?

Comment: This video describes how bazel coverage internals work, but it does not solve this issue.

Comment: Add filters as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447218/using-bazel-to-generate-coverage-report)

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the path that coverage has to check within parameter

> --instrumentation_filter="path1,path2,"

and so it will report them

https://bazel.build/configure/coverage