# Using Bazel monorepo, not able to generate coverage for Kotlin apps

Tags: kotlin, go, bazel, monorepo, bazel-rules

My Bazel monorepo, has apps in `Kotlin` and `Golang`. In the earlier versions (For Go/Kotlin Bazel rules), the support for code coverage was not there but in the later rules-versions it's supported as per the `rules_go` and `rules_kotlin` documentation.

When I run the below command, the code coverage for **only the Go apps** is generated but **not the Kotlin apps**. I have upgraded to the latest `rules_kotlin`.

```
bazel coverage --combined_report=lcov --nocache_test_results --instrumentation_filter=//apps:<app-name>:<test-name> //...:all
```

**FYI, following versions are used:**

- Bazel: 5.3.0
- Kotlin rules: v1.7.1
- Golang rules: v0.25.0

Comment: If you are trying to get the complete coverage this answer is [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447218/using-bazel-to-generate-coverage-report)

Comment: The answer mentioned above is about generating the coverage report from the .dat file. My problem is that in Bazel monorepo, the .dat file doesn't cover any non-Go file; which in my case is Kotlin. 

No coverage for the kotlin file is being generated in the _coverage.dat file.